# Php-mysql if statement is only taking the first condition as valid

Tags: php, mysql

$POST['query'] is an AJAX used variable which is a search box value... $plan will be the exact plan of the search customer. Based on the $plan variable the URL's must change according to the if statements. However regardless of $plan being changed the URL remains the same for all as "planA"..

I need PHP to jump according to the $Plan variable and pick up the right URL.

Please Help me!!

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","*****"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `create_customer` WHERE `Customer Id` LIKE '{$_POST['query']}%' LIMIT 6";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$plan = $user['Plan'];

 if ($plan = "planA") {
  
 while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
  echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
  
  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
  
echo $user['Plan'];
  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planA_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
  
 }

}
 
  if ($plan = "planB") {
 while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
  echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
  
  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
  

  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planB_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
  
 }
  }


      if ($plan = "planC") {
 while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
  echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
  
  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
  

  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planC_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
  
 } 
      }
 
 
           if ($plan = "planA1") {
 while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
  echo "<h2>".$user['Customer Name']."</h2>";
  
  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=".$user['id']."'>Update Profile Details</a></h4>";
  

  echo "<h4><a href='http://smjw.phatake.in/admin/planA1_details.php?recordID=".$user['Customer Id']."'>Receive Payment</a></h4>";
  
 } 
           
 
 
           }

 
else {
echo "<p style='color:red'>User not found...</p>";
}
```

Comment: You are using `=`. This is the assignment operator. Use `==`. This is the comparison operator. For eg, in the code above, `if($plan = "planA")` should be `if($plan == "planA")`.

Comment: Now after updating the code to == the last else statement is being executed by default @KishenNagaraju

Comment: Have you changed in all if statements ?

Comment: Yes @KishenNagaraju

Comment: That means the `$plan` variable is containing value other than which is mentioned in the if statements. Print out the `$plan` variable and check what is the value coming in that ? Also check the value in the database for that user as well.

Comment: Its always shows as planA. Not changing at all . Works in echo but not in print @KishenNagaraju

Comment: There is a lot of code duplication here which suggests that this can be simplified

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius : How to simplify this sir?

Comment: @DoorsShelters - I am just following on my previous conversation. Replace `if($plan == "planA")` with `if($plan == 'planA')`.

Comment: Its replaced. And when I do that it executes only the Else statement @KishenNagaraju

Comment: one refinement would be to have a single endpoint for the plans - rather than `planA_details`,`planB_details`...etc a single `plan_details` with the plan letter passed as a querystring parameter

Comment: within each block of `if( $plan=='planA ){ ... }'` etc virtually all the contents remain the same - planA is a little different perhaps.... these can be simplified

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius : I didn't get you?

Comment: Oh thanks Dharman !.. I need to fix the if statement first. And may be it would be helpful if you just let me know how to fix the SQL Injections part..

Comment: btw - it is not a great idea to have spaces in column names in your tables

Comment: Ok noted. Please help me on the URL changing part  @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 1):

Rather than multiple very similar pieces of code you could simplify to be more generic. I should point out this is an untested idea and added here only to illustrate the comment I made previously.

So, rather then calling `if ($plan = "planA") {` - which is incorrect anyway as you need to use `==` to test for equality - you should be able to do like this.

Use a single endpoint to handle all different plans and use some method ( querystring in this instance ) to differentiate which plan is being called. Note that below `planA_details.php` (same for B,C,A1) is now simply `plan_details.php` so you can, within that file, use `$_GET['plan']` to identify the plan selected. As with all user-supplied input care should be taken...

```
// previous & subsequent code remains "as-was"

$plan = $user['Plan'];

if( in_array( $plan, array('planA','planB','planC','planA1') ) ){
    
    while( $user=mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
        $letter=str_replace('plan','',$plan);
        printf('
            <h2>%s</h2>
            <h4><a href="//smjw.phatake.in/admin/cc.php?recordID=%s">Update Profile Details</a></h4>
            <h4><a href="//smjw.phatake.in/admin/plan_details.php?recordID=%s&plan=%s">Receive Payment</a></h4>',
            $user['Customer Name'],
            $user['id'],
            $user['Customer Id'],
            $letter
        );
    }
}
```